# Show that V is a subspace by expressing it as the span of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

What exactly is this question asking me to do? I think the use of the set notation has thrown me off a bit. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(1,2,1)'$ and $w=(3,5,3)'$ (here, $'$ denotes transposition) so that
$$
\iota\equiv(1,1,1)'=w-2v.
$$
Then 
$$
V=\{\iota+sv+tw=(s-2)v+(t+1)w:s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{sv+tw:s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
From this, you can see that $V$ is a subspace:

- $0\in V$: just let $s=t=0$
- If $x$ and $y$ are in $V$ with $x=s_xv+t_xw$ and $y=s_yv+t_yw$, then for scalars $a$ and $b$:
  $$
  ax+by=(as_x+bs_y)v+(at_x+bt_y)w\in V
  $$